# Using SPUserResizableView in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, github, resize

I'm trying to use the SPUserResizableView created by Spoletto in github (https://github.com/spoletto/SPUserResizableView).

I imported the .h and .m files, created a bridge and added the delegates to my controller.

I think problem is that problem is that the library is very old and that's why I get many errors in the .h and .m files so I can't use the library.

Errors - http://postimg.org/gallery/3bq2ldo0m/

Can you help me setup the library in swift?

Comment: Hi. Did you ever manage to figure this out? I'm trying to do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up an Objective-C bridging header and then import it in there. To do this:

1. Drag and drop the .h and .m SPUserResizableView files into your project.
2. When Xcode asks if you want to create a bridging header, select 'Yes'.
3. Type in the new file called 'YOUR-PROJECT-NAME-bridging-header.h' this code:

   `#import SPUserResizableView.h`
4. You should now be able to use it in Swift!

Answer (score 1):

I also got the same error, Just add these two in SPUserResizableView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

Your problem will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working with Swift 4 by moving the variable declarations from the interface to the implementation, and removing the release and dealloc code.

**SPUserResizableView.h changed to**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef struct SPUserResizableViewAnchorPoint {
    CGFloat adjustsX;
    CGFloat adjustsY;
    CGFloat adjustsH;
    CGFloat adjustsW;
} SPUserResizableViewAnchorPoint;

@protocol SPUserResizableViewDelegate;
@class SPGripViewBorderView;

@interface SPUserResizableView : UIView {
}

//...
//(identical from this point on)
```

**SPUserResizableView.m changed to**

```
    //...
    //(identical up to)

            //CGColorSpaceRelease(baseSpace), baseSpace = NULL;
            CGColorSpaceRelease(baseSpace);
        baseSpace = NULL;


        @implementation SPUserResizableView

    SPGripViewBorderView *borderView;
    UIView *contentView;
    CGPoint touchStart;
    CGFloat minWidth;
    CGFloat minHeight;

    // Used to determine which components of the bounds we'll be modifying, based upon where the user's touch started.
    SPUserResizableViewAnchorPoint anchorPoint;

    id <SPUserResizableViewDelegate> delegate;


    //@synthesize contentView, minWidth, minHeight, preventsPositionOutsideSuperview, delegate;


    //...
    //(this part identical)



    - (void)dealloc {
        [contentView removeFromSuperview];
    }

    @end
```

Comment: @Piyuesh, I posted the changes I made. Let me now if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot @James , I'll test it.